# ListPopupWindow doesn't display list correctly when keyboard hides

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

[image]I am hiding keyboard on click on the edit text which is an anchor view to list popup window but the list is shown at a wrong place not on the required anchor view. But it works perfectly fine if the keyboard is already hidden i.e. the list is shown at the right position.

**onCLick()**

```
 Utility.keyboardDown(getActivity());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                country.setHintTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.create_new_account_forgot_password_colorcode));
            } else {
                country.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.create_new_account_forgot_password_colorcode));
            }
            listPopupWindowCountry = new ListPopupWindow(getContext());
            countryPopupListAdapter = new CountryPopupListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countryList);
            setCountryPopUpWindow();
            listPopupWindowCountry.show();
            country.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.create_new_account_forgot_password_colorcode));
            break;
```

**METHOD setCountryPopUpWindow()**

```
 private void setCountryPopUpWindow() {
    listPopupWindowCountry.setAdapter(countryPopupListAdapter);
    listPopupWindowCountry.setAnchorView(country);
    listPopupWindowCountry.setModal(true);
    listPopupWindowCountry.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CountryModel countryModel = countryList.get(position);
            if ((Utility.getText(state) != null || Utility.getText(city) != null)
                    && !(Utility.getText(country).equals(countryModel.getName()))) {
                state.setText("");
                city.setText("");
            }
            country.setText(countryModel.getName());
            countryWrapper.setError(null);
            stateWrapper.setError(null);
            stateWrapper.setErrorEnabled(false);
            if (stateList != null) {
                stateList.clear();
            }
            AppPreferences.getInstance(getContext()).setPhoneCode(countryModel.getPhonecode() + "");
            countryID = countryModel.getId();
            stateList = new CountryStateCityFileHandler().getStates(countryModel);
            listPopupWindowCountry.dismiss();
        }
    });
    listPopupWindowCountry.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            listPopupWindowCountry.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: share your code.

Comment: ListPopupWindow auto adjust with keyboard state if open its will show upwards((i.e if there is no room)) and if close then it will show downwards.

Comment: @HemantParmar  I have updated the question please check

Comment: attach your screens here. what is your outcome and what you have aspect!

Comment: @Radhey i have uploaded the images first image is actual result and second image is the expected result

Comment: As @ADM suggested, it will occupy and auto adjust screen at the time of softkeybord hide and show. My suggestion is replace that #country edittext with just text view and set view/button below that so you can get exact look and feel like edittext.